# how to run same steps in loop with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

Let's say that I have a workflow file like:

```yaml
--
name: CI Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: build environment
        run: docker build Blah blah blah

      - name: run test ${{ env.FILE }}
        run: testcommand ${FILE}
        env:
          FILE: /tmp/file1

      - name: run test ${{ env.FILE }}
        run: testcommand ${FILE}
        env:
          FILE: /tmp/file2

      - name: run test ${{ env.FILE }}
        run: testcommand ${FILE}
        env:
          FILE: /tmp/file3

      - name: save logs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test_logs
          path: /tmp/logs
```

Here is `run test ${{ env.FILE }}` steps are exactly same and repeating itself. I want to use loop and pass only `FILE` parameter into it.

I tried to add `matrix`:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    ...
    strategy:
      matrix:
        test-case: ["/tmp/file1", "/tmp/file2", "/tmp/file3"]
    ...
    steps:
      - name: build environment
        ...

      - name: run test ${{ matrix.test-case }}
        run: testcommand ${FILE}
        env:
          FILE: ${{ matrix.test-case }}

      - name: save logs
        ...
...
```

But in this case all steps are running as different jobs and `build environment` and `save logs` also running three times. But I want to repeat only middle `run test` at the same environment created once on `build environment` step.

Also I tried to use `Anchors` to be able shorten code:

```yaml
...
      - &test-case
        name: run test ${{ env.FILE }}
        run: testcommand ${FILE}
        env:
          FILE: /tmp/file1

      - <<: *test-case
        env:
          FILE: /tmp/file2

      - <<: *test-case
        env:
          FILE: /tmp/file3
...
```

But I've got the error:

```
Anchors are not currently supported. Remove the anchor 'test-case'
```

No luck...

Of course, I'm able to create bash loop within one single step, but I want to separate steps because it easy to check which test is failed at GitHub Actions page.

So the question is: is it possible to run same steps in loop without repeating whole step code?

Comment: Looping over actions is not possible currently, you listed both next best workarounds: Matrix and doing a loop in bash. Maybe you can reduce the code by using composite actions and/or use [Docker container runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container) with your build and setup scripts